# How to fix "bad listbox index" problem in Listbox.curselection() , tkinter ,Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, tkinter

I'm trying to get the selection of a Listbox, as soon as someone select a selection.
I'm using some codes like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#skip

def onSelect(listid):
print(listid)

audioListbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",lambda event:onSelect(listid=str(audioListbox.curselection())))
videoListbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",lambda event:onSelect(listid=str(videoListbox.curselection())))
```

But what surprised me is, sometimes the function "Listbox.curselection()" will return an empty List when I select another Listbox, Like:
[something surprised me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yomxH.gif)

```
#result
(1,)    #select "audioListbox"
(1,)    #select "audioListbox"
()      #select "videoListbox"
(4,)    #select "videoListbox"
(3,)    #select "videoListbox"
()      #select "audioListbox"
```

Can anybody help me? please.....

Comment: Try adding `exportselection=False` to the creation of your two Listboxes.  The default behavior is for the selection to be tied to the system clipboard, so selecting anything in one box forces deselection of anything in the other box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `exportselection=False` to the listbox config.

```
audioListbox = tk.Listbox(window,exportselection=False)
```